# fseek with SEEK_CUR issue

Tags: c, fseek

```
#include <stdio.h>
main ()
{
 FILE *fs, *ft;
  char dest[20];
  fs = fopen ("STACKOVERFLOW.txt", "r");
  fseek (fs, 0, SEEK_END);
  fseek (fs, -3, SEEK_CUR);
  fgets (dest, 5, fs);
  printf ("dest value is %s ", dest);
}
```

My stack Overflow file  contains :

"I LOVE STACKOVERFLOW".

I was expecting the output 'LOW' as last 3 characters i am extracting.

But, my program prints  'OW' only.

What is the correct behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure that's all there is in the file? Because when I reproduce the problem, I did see `LOW`.

Comment: You probably have a newline character at the end of the line in the file and it is the last character followed by `W` and `O`

Comment: I think either you have space or next line character at the end of your string. Which is causing this issue.. To be sure use another test print statement and see where its output goes..

Comment: Seeking freely isn't supported through files opened in text mode. `fseek(fs, -3, SEEK_CUR)` could end up on a byte in the middle of a multibyte sequence in e.g. UTF-8 or UNICODE. With a Windows text file you'll probably only get "W".

Comment: @potrzebie  With text files, seeking the beginning and seeking to an offset previously found with `ftell()` are well defined.  Other seeks are not.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost certainly including the new line character at the end of the file. Try:

```
printf ("dest value is %s-xxx- ", dest);
```

and verify that -xxx- appears in the next line.